# RSA returns not expected result

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

below there is code for RSA algorithm :

```
def modexp(a,b,n):
    r =1
    for i in range(b):
        r =r * a% n
    return r

def  RSA(plaintext,p,q):
    encrypted =''
    decrypted=''
    n =p * q
    phi =(p-1)*(q-1)
    print("value of the  totient function is %d :"%(phi))
    e =int(input("enter some comprime number for e  accoridng phi : "))
    d =pow(e,-1,phi)
    for  letter in plaintext:
        encoding =modexp(ord(letter),e,n)
        encrypted =encrypted + chr(encoding)
    print("Encrypted version of %s plaintext is %s"%(plaintext,encrypted))
    for letter in encrypted:
        decoding =modexp(ord(letter),d,n)
        decrypted =decrypted +chr(decoding)
    print("Decrypted version of %s   is %s" % (encrypted, decrypted))



Name =input("enter you Name : ")
p =3
q =7
RSA(Name,p,q)
```

when i run program, i enter some text for instance computer , value for phi is 12, i choose some coprime number for instance 5, but it returns result like this :

```
enter you Name : computer
value of the  totient function is 12 :
enter some comprime number for e  accoridng phi : 5
Encrypted version of computer plaintext is 
Decrypted version of    is
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Btw, `modexp` is `pow`. You don't have to implement it yourself.

Comment: does pow  function  considers possible overflows?

Comment: What overflows? You mean modulo? Yes, that is what the third parameter is for. Also, `pow` is implemented more efficiently. Your implementation would run nearly indefinetely when confronted with key sizes that are used for actual productive encryption.

Comment: i mean if i take for instance 1000000  in power of 2000000 something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSA formula assumes a very large value of N, so that the message is less than that. In your case, for `N=21`, and input message `A`:

```
ord(A)=65=2 (mod N)
```

so after encrypting it and decrypting back, you will receive 2.

Besides, it's not safe to use RSA for data encryption (see [textbook RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/definition-of-textbook-rsa)), it's only used for symmetric key exchange.

Comment: thanks thanks, i got  it, what about  elliptic curve cryptography? is it save?

Comment: @datodatuashvili for elliptic curves they use Diffie-Helman ([ECDH](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/asymmetric-key-ciphers/ecc-encryption-decryption)) scheme to exchange symmetric keys.

Comment: Actually, RSA today mostly used in digital signatures with PSS padding. If you know [where KEM is used](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83470/18298), I would like to be happy to know.